# How to set Referrer in driver selenium python?

Tags: python

I need to scrape a web page, but the problem is when i click on the link on website, it works fine, but when i go through the link manually by typing url in browser, it gives Access Denied error, so may be they are validating referrer on their end, Can you please tell me how can i sort this issue out using selenium in python ?

or any idea that can solve this issue? i am unable to scrape the page because its giving Access Denied error.

PS. i am working with python3

Waiting for help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself by using seleniumwire ;) selenium doesn't support headers, but seleniumwire supports, so that solved my issue.
Thanks